# Can 2 PHP scripts launched separately interact with each other?

Tags: php, static-methods

Say I have this class

```
class Hello
{
    /**
     * Construct won't be called inside this class and is uncallable from
     * the outside. This prevents instantiating this class.
     * This is by purpose, because we want a static class.
     */
    private function __construct() {}
    private static $greeting = 'Hello';
    private static $initialized = false;

    private static function initialize()
    {
        if (self::$initialized)
            return;

        self::$greeting .= ' There!';
        self::$initialized = true;
    }

    public static function greet()
    {
        self::initialize();
        echo self::$greeting;
    }

    public static function changeGreet($new)
    {
        self::initialize();
        self::$greeting = $new;
    }
}
```

And I have 2 scripts, one that I run in the command line.

**cmdLine.php** (`php cmdLine.php`)

```
for($i = 0; $i < 25;$i++){
    echo Hello::greet() . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(5);
}
```

And one that I load up in a browser.

**browser.php**

```
Hello::changeGreet('NewGreet');
```

I thought, after first running cmdLine.php. and then loading the browser.php, the greeting would change the next time the loop ran, but it didn't.

**Is this something that's possible to do with just PHP?**

Comment: you can call shell commands via shell_exec http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php or similar functions. `$result = shell_exec("cmd")` will get you the full return string in one variable.

Comment: Sorry, it might not be clear, it's not the command line I have an issue with, I'm running that in a Terminal for this example, it's that the message being output from the command line script isn't changed when the browser.php script is ran.

Comment: I think both scripts are run by the server in seperate processes, so it is not possible. It would be if you used some storage that differrent processes can share (filesystem, database etc).

Comment: The browser and command line will be run in separate processes, and will therefore use different instances of the class. Without using some way of storing the state of the class, you won't get what you're after

Comment: That's what it seemed like was happening. Time to re-think my strategy on how to get something like this working then!

Comment: You’d be better off explaining your problem and use case rather than generic, “Can X do Y?” because there may be a better solution than the one you’ve already thought of and then trying to get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something that's possible to do with just PHP?: No.

Some sort of intermediary is required for this to work. A file, database, or something else would be needed.

(for instance)

In `initialize()`, you could have it open up a file with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and then store your greeting with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) when you need to change it.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but it's kind of what I thought the answer was going to be.